# How to 'tab backwards' (remove a tab or tab spaces) in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a fast way to tab backward without pressing backspace (however many number of spaces for which I've set my tab space)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'tab backwards'. Do you mean in edit mode to delete spaces that you've just inserted with tab or in exec mode to move back by more than one character at the time (backspace moves back by one char at the time ...) ?

Comment: The fastest way is to actually use tab characters for indentation. Then you have (with autoindent) one single keypress for all your indentation level shifts. In edit mode: One more level, press tab. Going back one level, press backspace. In command mode: arrow keys or h/l.

Comment: @hlovdal That can also be done by setting `softtabstop` without having to use actual tab characters in the file.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

If you're in insert mode:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> - shift left
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> - shift right

If you're in normal mode:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><<</kbd> - shift current line left
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>>></kbd> - shift current line right

If you're in visual mode and have 1 or more lines selected:

- `<` - shift selection left
- `>` - shift selection right

If you mean just to move backwards a word in normal mode, you can use `b` to go backwards a word.

Comment: didn't know that about insert mode

Comment: Wow, thanks. I knew about the << and >>, but those shifts whole line

Comment: I mapped Shift+Tab to C-d to make it work like it does in most IDEs.

Comment: Since it took me a few tries to make @Mo2 's suggestion work, here's how you map Shift+Tab to Ctrl+d: `inoremap <S-Tab> <C-d>`

Comment: I wish I knew it earlier. Thank you so much

Answer (score 22):

```
set softtabstop=4 expandtab
```

and you will be able to add up to four spaces when you press tab and remove up to four spaces by pressing `<BS>` once.

Comment: This answer should be selected instead of the existing selected one.

+ Very beginners may not know that this command should be entered in `~/.vimrc`, so be sure to let them know.

Answer (score 7):

*tl;dr: `set tabstop=4 softtabstop=-1 shiftwidth=0 expandtab`*

*short form: `set ts=4 sts=-1 sw=0 et`*

#### Explanation

If you set `softtabstop` (or `sts`) to `-1` it will automatically behave the
 same as `tabstop` (`ts`), which will save you some hassle if you change tabbing a lot.  Setting `shiftwidth` (`sw`) to `0` should effectively make
 that the same as `tabstop` as well.

#### In Detail

`shiftwidth` `sw`

> Number of spaces to use for each step of (auto)indent. Used for `cindent`, <kbd>>></kbd>, <kbd><<</kbd>, etc.
>   **When zero the `tabstop` value will be used.**

`tabstop` `ts`

> Number of spaces that a  in the file counts for.  Also see
>   [:retab](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aretab) command, and
>   `softtabstop` option.

`softtabstop` `sts`

> Number of spaces that a <kbd>Tab</kbd> counts for while performing editing
>   operations, like inserting a <kbd>Tab</kbd> or using <kbd>BS</kbd>.  It
>   *feels* like <kbd>Tab</kbd>s are being inserted, while in fact a mix of spaces
>   and s are used.  This is useful to keep the `tabs` is setting at its
>   standard value, while being able to edit like it is set to `sts`.  **When
>   `sts` is negative, the value of `shiftwidth` is used.** This will save you
>   some hassle if you change tabstops a lot.  When `expandtab` is not set, the
>   number of spaces is minimized by using <kbd>Tab</kbd>s.

`expandtab` `et`

> In Insert mode: Use the appropriate number of spaces to insert a .
>   Spaces are used in indents with the <kbd>></kbd> and <kbd><</kbd> commands
>   and when `autoindent` is on.  To insert a real tab when `expandtab` is on,
>   use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  See also
>   [:retab](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aretab)

Answer (score 3):

in normal mode, `<<` will tab the current line back one, in visual mode, `<` will make all selected lines tab back once

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766230/map-shift-tab-in-vim-to-inverse-tab-in-vim) has better answers for this in my opinion. Instead of using the `backspace` key to clear out 4 spaces at a time, `shift+tab` would be a great keyboard shortcut to use (since the `shift` modifier typically reverses the behavior of another shortcut). All other text editing software I'm familiar with uses this, but vim does not. However it's trivial to add this, and it means `softtabstop` doesn't need to be used:

```
set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=0 expandtab
inoremap <S-Tab> <C-d>
```

You can then use backspace to delete individual spaces and shift+tab to delete sets of 4 tabs when in insert mode. It also works if you want to stick to using tab characters.