# Track down double keybindings / conflicting keys

Tags: vim, conflict, key-bindings, keymapping

I'm trying to map Shift-Tab to unindent lines in insert mode.
Amongst [various mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766230/map-shift-tab-in-vim-to-inverse-tab-in-vim) this is what I like most:

```
inoremap <silent> <S-Tab> <C-d>
```

But whatever mapping I use Vim refuses to unindent a line. Instead it indents the line like a normal Tab.
But as soon as I re-source my .vimrc the mapping starts to work as expected. In order to avoid to have the keybinding mapped twice somewhere in my .vimrc I added the mapping to a blank .vimrc. Suprise it works.

Other mappings related to the tab key are:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Tab> :bnext<Cr>
nnoremap <silent> <S-Tab> :bprevious<Cr>
```

`ag/grep` does not show anything else mapped to tab.

How can I track down conflicting keybindings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
:verbose map <S-Tab>
```

it will show you the last place (file & line) it has been redefined.

Comment it and try again.

Comment: For insert mode, that would be `:verbose imap <S-Tab>` (or `:map!` would work, too).

Comment: @OP, You could also define the mappings as `<unique>` in your .vimrc. Plugins should also do this and leave the possibility to override the default mappings they provide.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I found the bugger (a plugin).