# Can't remap in vim

Tags: vim

I want to have shift-tab behave as it does in other text editors. However it just won't work for me

```
syntax on 

:set number 

filetype plugin indent on 

set tabstop=4 

set shiftwidth=4

set expandtab

inoremap <S-tab> <C-d>

colo ron
```

Does anyone know why the remap won't work?

**Edit:**
I already tried using the solution from [Map shift-tab in vim to inverse tab in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766230/map-shift-tab-in-vim-to-inverse-tab-in-vim). Also i'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map shift-tab in vim to inverse tab in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766230/map-shift-tab-in-vim-to-inverse-tab-in-vim)

Comment: Nope in fact I tried using amphetamachines answer before I posted the question.

Comment: Does your terminal differentiate between `<tab>` and `<s-tab>`? Check by going into insert mode and typing `<c-v>` then your key. Do this for both `<tab>` and `<s-tab>`. If they insert different characters then they can be mapped sperately

Comment: @ Peter Rincker  <tab> inserts spaces and <s-tab> inserts  ^[[Z.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tabedit](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages) to open more than one file at a time. Tabedit should allow you open and navigate between files the way you do in other editors. That includes the <tab> and <shift + tab> behavior you are probably expecting in [normal mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Normal).

open files with:

```
:tabedit <filename>
```

auto complete will work on file names with the tabkey, too. Example:

```
:tabe[tab] s<[tab]/R[tab]
```

might produce something like:

```
:tabedit source/Readme.txt
```

You can use tabs in your macros, too. So copying information in complex ways between files becomes something you can quickly do on the fly with macros.

Answer (score 0):

The linked solution works fine for me on Ubuntu 14.04, as well as using the commands in your question as my `.vimrc`.

Assuming you're storing the settings in your `.vimrc` file, did you reload the file after you made the change? You can do this by either relaunching vim, or running `:source ~/.vimrc`.

If that doesn't work, make sure you're in insert mode (`:i`/`:I`).

And if that doesn't work, make sure you aren't in paste mode (`:set nopaste`)